# tfs build 2010 add custom editor

Tags: tfsbuild

i add a custom editor for our custom process parameter but and add the assembly to "version control path to custom assemblies" and when i edit the build definition the editor not show, why?

when i add the assembly into The Visual Studio probing path it work

but i don't want to copy menualy the assembly to all cllints that use this build and so i want to use the assembly from the source control but then it don't work

i need i sulotion

my editor code:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace SVBuild
{

public class FolderBrowserEditor : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        if (context != null)
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;

        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None;
    }

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog fd;
        string path = "";
        string realPath = "";

        if (context == null || provider == null || context.Instance == null)
            return base.EditValue(provider, value);
        fd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fd.ShowNewFolderButton = true;
        fd.Description = "Select Folder";
        fd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = fd.SelectedPath;
            realPath = ResolveToUNC(path);
        }
        return realPath;
    }
    #region ResolveToUNC
    /// <summary>Resolves the given path to a full UNC path, or full local drive path.</summary>
    /// <param name="pPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private string ResolveToUNC(string pPath)
    {
        if (pPath.StartsWith(@"\\")) { return pPath; }

        string root = ResolveToRootUNC(pPath);

        if (pPath.StartsWith(root))
        {
            return pPath; // Local drive, no resolving occurred
        }
        else
        {
            return pPath.Replace(GetDriveLetter(pPath), root);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>Resolves the given path to a root UNC path, or root local drive path.</summary>
    /// <param name="pPath"></param>
    /// <returns>\\server\share OR C:\</returns>
    private string ResolveToRootUNC(string pPath)
    {
        ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();

        if (pPath.StartsWith(@"\\")) { return Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(pPath); }

        // Get just the drive letter for WMI call
        string driveletter = GetDriveLetter(pPath);

        mo.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", driveletter));

        // Get the data we need
        uint DriveType = Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]);
        string NetworkRoot = Convert.ToString(mo["ProviderName"]);
        mo = null;

        // Return the root UNC path if network drive, otherwise return the root path to the local drive
        if (DriveType == 4)
        {
            return NetworkRoot;
        }
        else
        {
            return driveletter + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Checks if the given path is on a network drive.</summary>
    /// <param name="pPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool isNetworkDrive(string pPath)
    {
        ManagementObject mo = new ManagementObject();

        if (pPath.StartsWith(@"\\")) { return true; }

        // Get just the drive letter for WMI call
        string driveletter = GetDriveLetter(pPath);

        mo.Path = new ManagementPath(string.Format("Win32_LogicalDisk='{0}'", driveletter));

        // Get the data we need
        uint DriveType = Convert.ToUInt32(mo["DriveType"]);
        mo = null;

        return DriveType == 4;
    }

    /// <summary>Given a path will extract just the drive letter with volume separator.</summary>
    /// <param name="pPath"></param>
    /// <returns>C:</returns>
    private string GetDriveLetter(string pPath)
    {
        if (pPath.StartsWith(@"\\")) { throw new ArgumentException("A UNC path was passed to GetDriveLetter"); }
        return Directory.GetDirectoryRoot(pPath).Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString(), "");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Several things might couse the issue.

1. Check the mappings for custom assembly
2. Once checked your stuff in into tfs, you must restart VS for it to work, the custom assembly contents are downloaded to temp folder once you open the process tab for the first time
3. Any assemblies in GAC or VS private assemblies will normally will win over the downloaded ones.
4. Make sure that your build parameter metadata has proper namespaces etc.
5. If editor is in referenced assembly you must include at least one activity for this assembly to be correctly loaded by workflow (not sure if this would impact process editor in VS, but will cause issues in build).

You can use another instance of VS to debug the one having issues, Module section will tell what stuff is loaded and from where, once there you can start to piece together the cause.

Update your question with more details if this doesn't resolve issue.

Comment: i did all these action check in to custom assembly and restart VS i ther is no assembly in the GAC OR private assembly the build parameter metadata is ok and ther is hes activity for this assembly and this donwt show. just when i copy the assembly to the private assembly it show but i want that it show to all client